# Load content on html page on page load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

It works without a problem, but since I am a beginner, I am not sure if this is the right way to do this. On my main html page I have a *div* that contains some product details. I want them to be loaded from my database and shown on the page as soon as the page loads. Something like on the www.amazon.com page. As soon as we load the page there are products with pictures, prices etc... This is the way I do it...

My HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body >

 <div id="PictureDiv"></div>
 <div id="NameDiv"></div>
 <div id="PriceDiv"></div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptjs"></script>
</body>
```

My JavaScript File:

```
OnPageLoad (); // executes as soon as the page loads

function OnPageLoad () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getProducts',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      $("#PictureDiv").html(data.pic);
      $("#NameDiv").html(data.name);
      $("#PriceDiv").html(data.price);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      // handle error
    }
});
}
```

So is this the way it is done or? Some advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: put your code  (the ajax call) inside `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /* your code here*/ });`  remove OnPageLoad function, its not required

Comment: So besides that is everything fine? Is this the way it is done?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready runs or executes when your DOM loaded, regarding ajax call I dont know how you set your page urls in your peoject, if 'getProducts' is a correct url, your ajax will work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for response dude. Have a nice day!

Comment: a more professional way of dealing with such is using [http://handlebarsjs.com/](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Easy to learn but it does the job perfect